# kafka-schema-registry-maven-plugin cannot download schema from schemaRegistryUrls in maven SpringBoot project

Tags: java, maven, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to use [kafka-schema-registry-maven-plugin](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/develop/maven-plugin.html#sr-maven-plugin) to download the latest kafka avro schema from the schemaRegistryUrls like this:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
                <artifactId>kafka-schema-registry-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.3.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>avro-resources</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>download</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaRegistryUrls>
                                <param>http://my-schema-registry-url.com</param>
                            </schemaRegistryUrls>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                            <subjectPatterns>
                                <param>^TestSubject000-(key|value)$</param>
                            </subjectPatterns>
                            <versions>
                                <param>latest</param>
                            </versions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

pluginRepositories:

```
<pluginRepository>
        <id>confluent</id>
        <url>https://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
```

However, after this configuration when I run `mvn clean install` , there is no file to be downloadedand I couldn't find any logs about `kafka-schema-registry-maven-plugin`. I am sure the `http://my-schema-registry-url.com` is working. Did I do anything wrong, how can make it works?

Comment: Try running it with the debug parameters `mvn clean install -X`

Comment: Thank you. Tried, still not show. My guess is kafka-schema-registry-maven-plugin is not being ran.

Comment: Ooh, you may need to use a special command on the command line to activate it. Maybe its documentation may have something about it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run something like this, based on your `phase` + `id` to test in manually...

```
mvn process-resources:avro-resources
```

Otherwise, you need to bind to a [Maven lifecycle event](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#setting-up-your-project-to-use-the-build-lifecycle), as are shown in the [workflow example](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/develop/maven-plugin.html#workflows-and-examples)

Note: `generate-resources` would make more sense than `process-resources`, as the Avro Maven plugin will want to run and *process* after the schemas had been downloaded (*generated*)